# Runtime Error 9 on Loop

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have three workbooks; all with information on the same policies, but come from different documents. I'm trying to copy the value of the same cell from each worksheet that has the same worksheet name in workbooks 1 & workbook 3. This is the code that I have:

```
Sub foo()

    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    Dim wbk2 As Workbook
    Dim wkb3 As Workbook
    Dim shtName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\Trad Reconciliation.xlsx")
    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\TradReconciliation.xlsx")
    Set wkb3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\Measure Trad Recon LS.xlsx")

    shtName = wkb2.Worksheets(i).Name

    For i = 2 To wkb2.Worksheets.Count
        wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("D3").Value = wkb1.Sheets(shtName).Range("D2")
        wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("E3").Value = wkb1.Sheets(shtName).Range("E2")
        wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("F3").Value = wkb1.Sheets(shtName).Range("F2")
        wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("D4").Value = wkb3.Sheets(shtName).Range("D2")
        wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("E4").Value = wkb3.Sheets(shtName).Range("E2")
        wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("F4").Value = wkb3.Sheets(shtName).Range("F2")
    Next i

End Sub
```

I don't understand how I'm using the subscript wrong. This is my first time coding VBA (first time in 5+ years), so I'm unfamiliar with coding errors.

Thank you!

Comment: Are all of the worksheets names in all 3 workbooks identical?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Dim i As Integer
>
> Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\Trad Reconciliation.xlsx")
> Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\TradReconciliation.xlsx")
> Set wkb3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\Measure Trad Recon LS.xlsx")
>
> shtName = wkb2.Worksheets(i).Name
> ```

Variable `i` is declared, but used before it's assigned - its value is therefore an implicit `0`.

With VBA collections being 1-based, that makes `wkb2.Worksheets(i)` be out of bounds.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

'...

shtName = wkb2.Worksheets(i).Name
```

Will fix it.

You probably want to move it inside the loop though.

Comment: Maybe with moving that `shtName = wkb2.Worksheets(i).Name` to after the `For i = ...`

Comment: @A.S.H possibly... it's not clear what `shtName` is supposed to be anyway ;-)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed that error but it gave me an Error 9 on the first line,

wkb2.Sheets(shtName).Range("D2").Value = wkb1.Sheets(shtName).Range("D2")

Comment: @leetontea you need to read your code out loud. Does it do what it's *supposed* to be doing? Either `wkb1` or `wkb2` does not have a worksheet named `shtName` - you need to decide what you're trying to do here.

Comment: There are 450 sheets, but I needed a quick way to take the value from the cell of one workbook to the other based on the name of the workbook. That line of code is supposed to take the D2 cell of wbk1 and paste it onto D2 cell of wbk2.
I know the correct input is Sheets("string"), but I thought if I set a variable to take on the name of each sheet, Sheets(shtName) would have worked.

Comment: Yes indeed, except you're working with 3 workbook objects here. One of them doesn't have the sheet name you're giving it. Your code is assuming that both `wkb1` and `wkb3` have all the sheets `wkb2` has. Apparently that isn't the case.

Comment: So in order for this macro to work, I need identical amount of worksheets?

Comment: What if I were to set another variable p as an integer, then use an if statement to see if the first worksheets have the same name. If it does, then it'll use execute that line. If it doesn't, then the p value will increase by 1.

I have prefaced that I have 0 experience on VBA. Never took a class. I started looking into it due to my job over the last day or two. I know what I want it to do, but I'm unsure of how to code it, so please bear with me!

Comment: Yes, verifying whether the sheet exists before you use it sounds like a good idea

Comment: `You probably want to move it inside the loop though.` is the money. As is verifying the sheets exist in `wkb1` & `wkb3` before trying to reference them.

Answer (score 0):

may be you're after this:

```
For i = 2 To wkb2.Worksheets.Count
    wkb2.Sheets(i).Range("D3:F3").Value = wkb1.Sheets(i).Range("D2:F2")
    wkb2.Sheets(i).Range("D4:F4").Value = wkb3.Sheets(i).Range("D2:F2")
Next i
```

Comment: This is very potentially it. ASSUMING that the sheet names all match and are in the same order. If that's not the case, this will work fantastically well, but won't produce the desired output. It will also fail if `wkb1` and/or `wkb3` have a different number of sheets than `wkb2`. This is a great foundation to wrap some error checking around.